# Is sequence unpacking atomic?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, atomic

Is sequence unpacking atomic? e.g.:

```
(a, b) = (c, d)
```

I'm under the impression it is not.

Edit: I meant atomicity in the context of multi-threading, i.e. whether the entire statement is indivisible, as atoms used to be.

Comment: I am under the impression that you are perhaps misunderstanding by what is *commonly* understood by atomicity in software development. Are you talking about thread safety here, or are you wondering if `a = c` will be executed before `b = d`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - If OP was wondering about the latter, OP would be very confused why something like `(a, b) = (b, a)` would work to swap values. It must be a question about thread safety.

Comment: @TedHopp: The question is way too vague to call this, and in my experience tuple unpacking causes plenty of confusion in and of itself.

Comment: "atomicity" means 'in one, indivisible step' in computer languages. If something is atomic, that means that the operation *cannot* be interrupted by another thread.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is one operation; the right-hand expression is evaluated before the left-hand assignment is applied:

```
>>> a, b = 10, 20
>>> a, b
(10, 20)
>>> b, a = a, b
>>> a, b
(20, 10)
>>> a, b = a*b, a/b
>>> a, b
(200, 2)
```

Or, if you are talking about multi-threaded environments, then the assignment is *not* atomic; the interpreter evaluates a tuple assignment with a single opcode, but uses separate opcodes to then store the results into each affected variable:

```
>>> def t(self): a,b=20,20
... 
>>> dis.dis(t)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 ((20, 20))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
              9 STORE_FAST               2 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

However, *normal* assigment is always going to be at least two opcodes (one for the right-hand expression, one for storing the result), so in python *in general* assigment is not atomic. Sequence unpacking is no different.

Comment: I think it not `atomic` expression. even `j = i +1` not atomic in high level languages. I have `Semaphore` in python.... I misunderstood the question?

Comment: That doesn't really establish that it's atomic. The question is whether `a` and `b` are assigned their values atomically (that is, as an indivisible operation) in a concurrent environment. I don't believe that they are; that is, if `(a, b)` are supposed to end up with values `(200, 2)` in the last step, another thread might see `(200, 10)` or `(20, 2)`.

Comment: I misunderstood the question (or rather, I opted to interpret the very sparse question in terms of the more commonly asked question about tuple assigments). I've updated it to include thread-safety information.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I *strongly* suspect that the OP doesn't understand what is commonly meant by atomicity. I've asked for a clarification.

Answer (score 9):

Definitely not atomic in a multi-threaded environment, tested using the following script:

```
import threading

a, b = 10, 10
finished = False
def thr():
    global finished
    while True:
        # if sequence unpacking and assignment is atomic then (a, b) will always
        # be either (10, 10) or (20, 20).  Could also just check for a != b
        if (a, b) in [(10, 20), (20, 10)]:
            print('Not atomic')
            finished = True
            break

t = threading.Thread(target=thr)
t.start()

while True:
    for i in range(1000000):
        a, b = 20, 20
        a, b = 10, 10
    if finished:
        t.join()
        break
```

Tested using CPython 2.6, 2.7, and 3.2.  On each version this script printed 'Not atomic' and exited in well under a second.

Comment: You made me recheck the opcodes; the unpack is one, but then there are two STORE_FAST opcodes, one for each variable affected. Plenty of chances for another thread to assign something different to in between.