# Is Python unpacking thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, thread-safety, atomic

Is an operation like `x,y = self.mytuple` atomic in Python ?

Or could `self.mytuple` be modified by another thread during the assignment, leading to x refering to the first version of self.mytuple, and y to the second version?

I'm using Python 3.

Comment: Rule of thumb: *Nothing* is thread-safe except locking one of the built-in locks (i.e. if you need thread safety, lock yourself). This rule has the benefit of remaining true in other Python implementations (and other versions of the ones you know) and when duck-typing leads to a user-defined class being used where you'd expect a built-in one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is thread-safe *only if item access is not handled by Python code*.

The unpacking is handled by one bytecode:

```
>>> def f():
...     a, b = self.mytuple
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (self) 
              3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (mytuple) 
              6 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2 
              9 STORE_FAST               0 (a) 
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (b) 
             15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None) 
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Provided `self.mytuple` is really a standard Python `tuple`, that is threadsafe.

As soon as accessing items from `mytuple` triggers a custom `__getitem__`, all bets are off.

Comment: Then that would be thread safe, since the unpacking of the sequence must be done locally. (x and y are also local variables in my example)

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional: indeed, misunderstood where the OP wanted thread safety. Adjusted.

Comment: Thanks. I also read your reply here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649684/is-sequence-unpacking-atomic that clarified it for me.

Comment: It's my original question "Is Python parallel assignment thread safe?" that was misleading. I was in fact wondering about the atomicity of unpacking.