# Is Python unpacking atomic w.r.t. interrupts?

Tags: python, interrupt, opcode, keyboardinterrupt

Given the following example

```py
try:
    a, b = 0, 0
    for _ in range(100):
        a, b = (a+1, b+1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    assert a == b
```

could an `AssertionError` be thrown? If so, is there a way to prevent it, i.e. to ensure that either both of `a` and `b` or none is updated on every iteration?

---

Possibly related to [Is Python unpacking thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880986/is-python-unpacking-thread-safe?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Within, the following example and corresponding opcode are given:

```py
>>> def t(self): a,b=20,20
... 
>>> dis.dis(t)
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               2 ((20, 20))
              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
              9 STORE_FAST               2 (b)
             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Since there are two separate instructions for storing `a` and `b`, I would expect that no guarantees can be given whether both or none of the two instructions is executed prior to a `KeyboardInterrupt`.

Comment: The only way to make this atomic is for there to be a single assignment, of a tuple perhaps : `ab = (ab[0]+1, ab[1]+1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: while Python will handle the interrupt internally and re-expose it separately (so interrupts are not quite as fraught as they are in C), as noted in e.g. PEP 343:

> Even if you write bug-free code, a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception can still cause it to exit between any two virtual machine opcodes.

Comment: Interestingly, purely as an implementation detail of the current version of CPython , if I'm reading the code correctly, signal handling and GIL swaps are only checked for on certain instructions (e.g. any instruction which calls a function or could trigger a backwards jump, with the latter indicating the end of a loop jumping back to the top; if it includes `CHECK_EVAL_BREAKER` it's an instruction that can end with signal handling or GIL swap, others can't). In practice, I believe it's impossible to see an interrupted unpack on the current implementation. No guarantee it stays safe though.